# My JSP is not taking the updated values from database using refresh header in servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

In my Java web application I used servlets (controller) and JSP (view) and POJO classes. I am running my application for every 10 seconds and storing the updated values of  selected URL from drop down list into database. And in my servlet I am fetching those values and forwarding to JSP that will display updated values of that selected URL. I used

```
 response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet");
```

Here my JSP looks like: In the top frame I have drop down list. I select one URL and clicks submit button for one time. And results of that selected option(URL) are displayed in bottom frame. And the second time onwards the page will be refreshed automatically using above `setHeader(--)` method updated values should be displayed in bottom frame automatically. In my *SiteAvailabilityServlet* I am getting the selected URL as

```
  request.getParameter("urlsel");
```

Giving me the correct selected URL in JSP(browser) for the first time by manually selecting..                                                                       But when it call above

```
response.setHeader(----);
```

for refreshing automatically it is taking the *urlsel* as null and not displaying updated values. How to solve this problem? Please help me.

Even If I use HTML meta tag it is taking null value from drop down list.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, then the problem is that you are loosing request parameter after first time you loading the page. Try to include parameter value into refresh url, e.g.:

```
response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet?urlSel=" + valueProdivedDuringTheFirstCall);
```

So, your servlet logic for bottom frame will look like:

```
// parameter passed from top frame
final String parameterName = "urlsel";
// read the value
String url = request.getParameter(parameterName);

// business logic, e.g. reading the stats and populating 
// the scope values to be provided to the view

// provide url value as a parameter for refresh request
response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet?urlSel=" + url);
```

Comment: here urlSel is parameter name and valueProvidedDuringTheFirstCall is the parameter value right?can I take any string name as urlSel(i.e., parameter name)

Comment: Yes, it is the name of the parameter and its value. You should use the same name you use when passing the value from the top frame.

Comment: where to use the urlSel in my code after response.setHeader()..Sorry I am unable to get you.Please help me..

Comment: :please help me..I am getting null value

Comment: The only place you use the value - is your business logic. Passing it to refresh url just saving parameter value for next request (when refresh happened). Please post more details if you need further details.

Comment: Still getting the null value after passing parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the **ursel** parameter with the SiteAvailabilityServlet

```
response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet?ursel="+urlsel);
```

Comment: you are already using in SiteAvailabilityServlet right?? have u checked the code i have included in answer? i'm passing ursel in that as parameter.